# Как мне реализовать собственный вывод графики на экран?

Tags: c++, c, графика

Как мне реализовать собственный вывод графики на экран типа `BitBit`/`SetDIBitsToDevice` /`Present`,что угодно,хоть самый топорный и медленный,хочу заглянуть под капот. Не использовать `BitBit`,а узнать что внутри. Каким образом выводят графику в окошечко. Или все что я пишу это невозможно?

Если кто спросит зачем это надо - мне очень нравятся велосипеды, особенно те которые я сам собрал. Почему не подходит способы что я описал выше, а так же решения предлагаемые в DirectX \ OpenGL? Подходят, просто мне интересно узнать как это реализовывается и хочу научиться.

Comment: Не встречал решение "под капот", обычно работают или через контекст устройства DC, как раз BitBit даёт пожалуй хороший результат, если не ошибаюсь SetBitmapBits даёт лучший результат. Если вам этого мало - используйте OpenGL (он по проще) или DirectX для ускорения графики.

Comment: По моему опыту картинка 8000x8000 (карта) на компе 10-летней давности с 1Ghz  рендерилась секунды 2-5 и перемещение было рывками. При переходе на OpenGL картинку можно было переносить без проблем даже на P2 266 Hz на котором задерка рендеринга при скроле картинки была 0,5-1 сек.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я наверное не так задал вопрос раз раз мне предлагаете использовать DirectX\OpenGl. Сейчас поправлю вопрос. Дело в том,что это не круто ездить на чужой машине и не знать как  и из чего она состоит. В этих библиотеках по сути тоже свой вывод графики,вот я и хочу понять что мне сделать\ что смотреть что бы узнать что внутри х) я же не пишу что они плохо выводят и медленные,я пишу что хочу узнать как делается

Comment: Хотите узнать что внутри BitBtn ? Берёте дизассемблер, например IDA Pro (можно найти бесплатные версии). Открываете dll долго нудно копаете. Я копал - ничего стоящено не нашёл. Может у вас получится.

Comment: @nick_n_a я почему-то думал есть решения проще._. Немного обнадёжил тот факт,что уже не тупик. Спасибо

Comment: Возможно изучение DDK  и драйвера видеокарты что-то даст. Только работа с драйверами тоже такое себе удовольствие.

Comment: @nick_n_a и это всё на asm придётся делать получается?

Comment: Не обязательно. С++ неплохо переводит в машинный код. Как минимум вам нужно понять как это вообще делать, на с++ это будет проще чем на ассемблере. А за тем, если будут участки, например где нужно копировать большие куски памяти - то можно оптимизировать ассемблерными вставками, или отдельные процедуры собрать на чистом ассемблере, но это уже второй этап. си/с++ вполне подходит для того что бы на нём реализовать даже ядро ОС. Загрузчик - на ассемблере, а остальное си/с++. Если вы пишите без ос, то можно писать сразу в видеопамять. Но под виндой всё сложно.

Comment: xf86-video-nv - NVIDIA video driver for the Xorg X server: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-nv (версию драйвера с 3d-acceliration они не открывали)

Comment: @Chorkov а ты в курсе что во всех созданных ими проектами используется Xlib ? Это немного не то что я хотел,а точнее вообще не то.Я хочу разобраться что внутри,а не разбирать очередную библиотеку с готовыми функциями и закрытыми исходниками._.

Comment: 90% драйверов, в т ч драйвер видео - состоят из двух частей. Из клиентской dll (API), это gdi32.dll (грубо), или opengl длл-ки и драйвера.Это dll верхнего уровня. Они "открывают" драйвер, и делают туда какие-то запросы (или напрямую или через дополнительные dll). Вы можете 1) попытаться через либу найти запросы к драйверу, или наоброт в исходниках драйвера найти точки, через которые можно взаимодействовать с драйвером. Поэтому если вы хотите закинуть изображение в обход GDI opengl directx - то копайте уровень драйвера. Возможно также можно получить доступ к видеокарте через промежуточные dll.